# linked lists displays in reverse

Tags: c, list

I was trying a single linked list. After creating the list, it tries to display in forward order, but it displays in reverse. I guess I am adding nodes in forward position but why does it display from the last input value?

Here is the code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
void add(num);
void insert();
void display();
struct node
{
int val;
struct node *next;
};

struct node *head =NULL;

main()
{

int data,i=0;
head = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
while(1)
    {
      printf("enter your choice");
      scanf("%d",&i);

      switch(i)
       {
         case 1:
         insert();
         break;

         case 2:
         display();
         break;

         default:
         printf("thankyou");

        }

      }



}

void add(num)
{
  struct node *temp;
  temp=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  temp->val=num;
  if (head== NULL)
      {
       head=temp;
       head->next=NULL;
      }
  else
      {
       head->next = temp
       head=temp;
      }
}

void insert()
{
  int ch;
  if (head->val == NULL )
     {
       printf("Enter the value for the first node :");
       scanf("%d",&ch);
       add(ch);
      }
  else if(head->val != NULL)
      {
       printf("Enter the value to insert :");
       scanf("%d",&ch);
       add(ch);
      }
  }

void display()
{
 struct node *newnode;
 newnode = head;
  if(newnode == NULL)
       printf("invalid list");
  else
     {
       while(newnode!=NULL)
        {
          printf("%d \t\t",newnode->val);
          newnode=newnode->next;

         }
     } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append each new entity at the end of the list:

```
void add(num)
{
  struct node *temp, *temp2;
  temp=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  temp->val=num;
  if (head== NULL)
      {
       head=temp;
       head->next=NULL;
      }
  else
      {
       temp2 = head;
       while (temp2->next != NULL)
            temp2 = temp2->next;

       temp2->next = temp;
       temp->next = NULL;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing

```
    head->next = temp;
    head=temp;
```

do

```
    temp->next=head;
    head=temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

The code does not look good to me, because at the end of all insertions the head points to the last element of the list with the `next` field uninitialized. This does not print the list in reverse, this will print the last element inserted and then the behaviour will be undefined. Also, as you loose the head pointer, you have lost the list and all the allocated memory (leak).

I will recommend to maintain a `tail` pointer which will always point to the tail of the list. An append function can just add a new node after the `tail` and update the `tail` by advancing it. The `head` remains the same and points the first element of the list. You can also assign the value of `head` into a temporary variable, iterate to the end of the list, and insert, but in this case the insertion will be costly.